# HTML5: Server-sent-events

Tags: html, events, client, reconnect

I have some questions to html5 server-sent-events.

The client always tries to reconnect after a connection is closed. I know the server can define the time before a reconnection with `printWriter.write("retry: 5000\n")`. But it is also possible that the client can define this? Or how can I prevent the reconnection on client side?

My other question is how the server can throw an error to the client. The client has an errorhandler `eventsource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {...}, false);`. So there must be a way to throw errors?!